# Box2d lag when removing bodies & sprites

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am working on a game, which involves bombs etc. When the bomb goes off I call `world->getBodyList();`, to get a list of all of the bodies and then the ones near enough get destroyed. I remove them with the method `removeSpriteAndBody` found in the BodyNode class.

It works and all, but it lags just a little bit when the bomb goes off and the bodies/sprites get removed. How can I fix this?

I remove the all in the 'tick' method, by flagging the for removal. However I do have  a few 'removeBody' calls around the place which make no difference if I take out or not.

The funny thing is, is that it only happens the first two or three ties you use a bomb. After that it is as smooth as butter!

Comment: Are you sure it's the removal and not perhaps the visual effect or other things happening when the bomb goes off?

Comment: It could be I guess. The only visual effects are just creating/removing a few sprites which an explosion png. But if it was that then I don't understand why it would be fine after the first few goes. It's not that there are less bodies/sprite on the screen either. I can go back to level one and it will be fines as long as it isn't the first time. Strange.

Comment: I would first try just not drawing the explosion as LearnCocos2D suggests. If there are a large number of bodies in the world, you would be better off using QueryAABB to find the closest ones efficiently.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into the QueryAABB thing. Never used it before, but have seen it at least. My guess about the lag would be the app having to initialize the body object world.GetBodyList() generates. Retrieving all of the bodies on te screen must be expensive and is causing the lag. Then maybe it caches some of it in some way do it is faster the second time.....